# Replace part of string using Regex if this part contains additional spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace all `"12-12"` to `"12:00 AM - 12:00 AM"`

For this I've created some logic for replacement :

```
IDictionary<string, string> Replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "12-12".ToUpperInvariant(), "12:00 AM - 12:00 AM"}
};

Regex AliasReplacementRegex = new Regex(string.Join("|", Replacements.Keys),
    RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var input = AliasReplacementRegex.Replace(token, m => Replacements[m.Value.ToUpperInvariant()]);
```

where `token` is parameter.

In one of my cases I have input string like `"Mo-Th: 12 - 12"`
How can I match it? 
It is almost what I expect except additional spaces? 
Is there any option except adding it to my Regex Rules?

---

UPD : 
Is next update correct solution for my case? seems like it is working, but maybe some case which will breal it all.

```
Regex AliasReplacementRegex = new Regex(string.Join("|", Replacements.Keys),
        RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Comment: Is it only ever `12-12`?  Or is it sometimes other times?

Comment: Then search for all the various combinations: `12 - 12`, `12- 12`, `12 -12`

Comment: @xanatos -- So what happens if its got more than one space in a row?

Comment: What's the difference between `"12-12"` and it's uppercase version?

Comment: If your keys are regex patterns, replace `"12-12"` with `@"\b12\s*-\s*12\b"`. `.ToUpperInvariant()` is useless, digits have no case.

Comment: This is not that easy, but actually there was such a question before. No idea how to find it. :(

Comment: remove whitespace with this string.replace(" ","")
then you can split the string by var val=string.split('-') 
and create a new by val newstring=string.format($"{val[0]}:00 AM - {val[1]}:00 AM")
Btw, how do you know if it is am or pm?

Comment: See http://ideone.com/ql2qXj

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, cause I have in rules some other like "noon", "daily" etc.

Comment: @rory.ap, in case others times "1-1", "2-2" etc... For that cases it is ok. Parser will know what to do with them, but 12-12 is parsed as 12AM - 12 PM... should be 12AM - 12 AM

Comment: Where do you expect whitespaces in your keys? At any location? How do you know where to match additional whitespace and where not?

Comment: Where do you expect whitespaces in your keys? At any location? How do you know where to match additional whitespace and where not? Or do you want to make the dictionary key search whitespace-insensitive?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I get this hours from response. Based on all my cases this hours can be received in format with spaces "12 - 12" or without "12-12". Maybe another cases also possible. Yes, something like whitespace-insensitive I think will help.

Answer (score 0):

You may build a dynamic regex to match any 0+ whitespace symbols around `-` in your input text, and then implement a custom IEqualityComparer to look up values using "whitespace-insensitive" keys:

```
public class WhitespaceInsensitiveComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return string.Join("", x.Where(m => !char.IsWhiteSpace(m))) == string.Join("", y.Where(m => !char.IsWhiteSpace(m)));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string x)
    {
        return string.Join("", x.Where(m => !char.IsWhiteSpace(m))).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and then

```
var token = "Mo-Th: 12 - 12";
var comparer = new WhitespaceInsensitiveComparer();
var Replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>(comparer);
Replacements.Add("12-12", "12:00 AM - 12:00 AM");
var AliasReplacementRegex = new Regex(string.Join("|", Replacements.Keys.Select(m => 
     Regex.Replace(m, @"\s*-\s*", @"\s*-\s*"))), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var input = AliasReplacementRegex.Replace(token, m => Replacements[m.Value]);
```

See a [C# demo online](https://ideone.com/oIAdDW).